# Repeating matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a square matrix say n by n; I want to expand this matrix to n^2 by n^2 such that values in the position are repeated. 
e.g A matrix is 

2 3
5 6

I want to generate matrix B such that

2 2 3 3 
2 2 3 3 
5 5 6 6 
5 5 6 6

How can this be done in matlab? And need to be generalized for any square matrix

Additional question: If I want to duplicate like following 
2 3 2 3 
5 6 5 6 
2 3 2 3 
5 6 5 6

How this can be archived ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Kronecker tensor product:

```
B = kron(A,ones(n));
```

Comment: `kron` is the best. I would add `B=kron(ones(n),A)` for the second question.

Answer (score 1):

Let the data be

```
M = [2 3; 5 6];   % initial matrix
v = 2;            % vertical repetition factor 
h = 3;            % horizontal repetition factor
```

In addition to using **`kron`** as shown by [@Omg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042895/repeating-matrix-in-matlab/46042932#46042932), you can do it using just **indexing**:

```
result = M(ceil(1/v:1/v:end), ceil(1/h:1/h:end));
```

Or, in recent Matlab versions, you can use **[`repelem`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)**:

```
result = repelem(M, v, h);
```

Either of the above gives

```
result =
     2     2     2     3     3     3
     2     2     2     3     3     3
     5     5     5     6     6     6
     5     5     5     6     6     6
```

Comment: Additional question: If I want to duplicate like following 
2 3 2 3 <br/>
5 6 5 6 <br/>
2 3 2 3 <br/>
5 6 5 6 <br/>

How this can be archived ?

Comment: @Aditya That's easier: `repmat(M, v, h)`